# How to return a List<string> from string parameters of action method MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on MVC 5 project.

```
string hdPrimUserFirstReg = "{\"ProjectName\":\"wwwwwww\",\"ClientName\":\"asdw\",\"ProjectType\":\"2\",\"ProjectLocation\":\"asdfasdfs\",\"Status\":\"Completed\"},\"Form6\":null}","hdPremUserProject":"","hdclientLogo":"","hdProjectTitle":"","ProjectName":"eeeeeee","ClientName":"asdwedfswe","ProjectType":"1","ProjectLocation":"dfwea","Status":"Completed}";
```

[image]

I want to create a list of `ProjectName` from the variable `hdPrimUserFirstReg` JSON format data and also from the `Form 5` into the `public IList<string> listProjectName { get; set; }`

And this is my java-script,

```js
AddProjectList: function (e) {

        debugger;
        if (this.validateForm()) {
            debugger;
            var hidvalue = $('#hdPrimUserFirstReg').val();//// hidden field from same form 
            var hidJson = JSON.parse(hidvalue);
            var json = {};

            $.each($('#frmSubmitPremUserRegFirst').serializeArray(), function (i, field) {
                json[field.name] = field.value || '';
            });           

            hidJson.Form5 = json;

            var str = JSON.stringify(hidJson);

            $('#hdPrimUserFirstReg').val(str); // hidden field from same form 

        }
    },
```

Error: cannot deserialize the current json object (e.g. {“name”:“value”}) into type 'system.collections.generic.list`1

How can I do this ?

Please help me...

Comment: your json string is invalid

Comment: the string contain long value. So... I want to get only 'Projectname' from the json string.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var listProjectName = JsonConvert .DeserializeObject<List<hdPrimUserFirstRegModel>>(pageVM.hdP‌​rimUserFirstReg ).Select(x => x.ProjectName).ToList()
```

Comment: The 'hdPrimUserFirstReg ' inside 'Form5'. How can I get ?

Comment: pageVM.hdPrimUserFirstReg

Comment: okay, but I want creat only list of projectname, but the pageVM.hdPrimUserFirstReg contain lot of items.

Comment: ok, var listProjectName = 
          JsonConvert
             .DeserializeObject<List<hdPrimUserFirstRegModel>>(pageVM.hdPrimUserFirstReg ).Select(x => x.ProjectName).ToList() ;

Comment: no build error, but occurred run time error: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1'

Answer (score 1):

```
var hdPrimUserFirstRegList = 
          JsonConvert
             .DeserializeObject<List<hdPrimUserFirstRegModel>>(pageVM.hdPrimUserFirstReg );
var projectsNames = hdPrimUserFirstRegList.Select(x=>x.ProjectName).toList();
```

And create model `hdPrimUserFirstRegModel`contains all json object properties.

Comment: no build error, but occurred run time error: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1'

Comment: @AbhiJA because this is not a valid json, you can test it online first http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: sir, could you please check my jscript code. I have updated my question. There is hiddenfield 'hdPrimUserFirstReg' that holding data by form 1,Form 2 etc. So I can not rearrange json inside same hiddenfield.